# Call static (async) method with generic type constraint, with type name (string)

Tags: c#, generics, static-methods

I need to call a static method (of a helper class) which has a generic type constraint like this:

```
public static ResultType SomeMethod<T>(string someParm) 
    where T : SomeBaseClass
```

How can I call this method if I only know `T` by its name (string)?

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384976/c-sharp-calling-a-static-method-using-a-type), but I could not figure out how to use [`MethodBase.Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx) in my case.

**UPDATE**

After this was flagged as duplicate, I realised I should have asked if the static method is an `async` method with optional parameters.

```
public async static Task<ResultType> SomeMethod<T>(string someParm, 
    string optionalParm) where T : SomeBaseClass
```

Then I found this answer: [.NET invoke an async method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16153047/net-invoke-async-method-and-await). Basically, invoking an async method would return what you expect it to return, which is generally either a `Task` or `Task<>`. Bleeding obvious now, LOL

Then, I was getting `Parameter mismatch count`. It turned out I had to provide all parameters, and specify `Type.Missing` for optional parameters where I want the method to use the default value.

Comment: How about [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/232621/5240004)?

Comment: Hi @theB, @Blorgbeard, what happens if the method I wish to call is async: `public async static TasK<ResultType> SomeMethodAsync<T>(string someParm)`. I can't seem to work it out.

Comment: Don't worry, I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16153047/net-invoke-async-method-and-await