# Blazor component not refresh after event fired

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

My component contains a Table, I'm calling a func that fire an event when I click on a row like this:

```
<tr class="@(EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(SelectedItem, rowValue.Key) && HasSelectedItem == true ? "data-grid-body-row-selected" : "data-grid-body-row")" @onclick="@(() => SetSelectedItem(rowValue.Key))">
   @foreach (RowData rowData in rowValue.Value) {
      <td>@rowData.Value</td>
   }
</tr>

public event EventHandler ItemSelected;

private void SetSelectedItem(T item) {
    SelectedItem = item;
    HasSelectedItem = true;
    ItemSelected.Invoke(this, null);
}
```

The problem is, when I fire `ItemSelected` event, the class of the `<tr>` is not updated, however when I remove the line `ItemSelected.Invoke(this, null);` everything works fine again.

On my parent component I have this:

```
private MyComponent<Person> _ref;

protected override void OnInitializedAsync() {
   _ref.ItemSelected += ItemSelected;
}

protected virtual void ItemSelected(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   MyComponent<Person> _tmpref = (MyComponent<Person>)sender;
   SelectedPerson = _tmpref.SelectedItem;
   StateHasChanged();
}
```

and I get the correct Item selected, so I have tried to place `StateHasChanged()` before and after my Invoke in my component but nothing changed. I can't find what's the problem.

**Edit**

```
private async Task SetSelectedItem(T item) {
   SelectedItem = item;
   HasSelectedItem = true;
   await Task.Run(() => ItemSelected.Invoke(this, null));
}
```

Now it works for few seconds and it get back to the previous state.

**Solution**

```
private async Task SetSelectedItem(T item) {
   SelectedItem = item;
   await Task.Run(() => ItemSelected.Invoke(this, null));
   HasSelectedItem = true;
}
```

I Simply moved my HasSelectedItem = true after the Invoke and now it works but I don't understand why it get back to false if I place it before, while my SelectedItem stay at the good value if I let it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SetSelectedItem` should be async and `ItemSelected` awaitable (for example returning a Task). Then the onclick event will correctly wait for the event handler to execute instead to immediately complete without effect, like it does now, because it terminates before the changes have taken effect.

Comment: It works for few secondes and then it get back to the previous state, see edit for the new code

Comment: var result = ItemSelected.Invoke(this, null);
await result;

Comment: It is ItemSelected that must be awaited... If you wrap it in a Task.Run and await it, but the function that wraps it is not async and not awaited, then it does not actually wait for it...

Comment: I have compile error, Cannot assign void to an implicity-typed variable, I also forget to precise the type of my event: `event EventHandler ItemSelected;`

Comment: Then cast to (Task) (or let it return and be Task<some return type>). replace var with Task or Task<that type>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16153047/net-invoke-async-method-and-await