# How to call a generic async method using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, async-await

```
public interface IBar {
}
public class Bar : IBar {
}
public class Bar2 : IBar {
}
public interface IFoo {
  Task<T> Get<T>(T o) where T : IBar;
}
public class Foo : IFoo {
  public async Task<T> Get<T>(T o) where T : IBar {
    ...
  }
}
```

I can then call this method using reflection:

```
var method = typeof(IFoo).GetMethod(nameof(IFoo.Get));
var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(bar2.GetType());
var task = generic.Invoke(foo, new [] { bar2 });
```

How do I await on this `Task`? and How do I cast it to `Task<bar2.GetType()>`?

Comment: The answer is to cast it since it returns a object (see @Fabio). However you should make sure that `Foo` does inherit `IFoo`, if not you'll get an exception because `foo` (supplied at the `Invoke`) is the wrong type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to await an async private method invoked using reflection in WinRT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711585/how-to-await-an-async-private-method-invoked-using-reflection-in-winrt)

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Because `Task<T>` derives from `Task` you can await on just that, once the task is awaited you can use reflection to safely access the `.Result` property via reflection.

Once you have the result you will either need to store it in a `IBar` and use the methods and properties on that or cast to the specific type after testing to use the type specific methods.

Here is a full MCVE of it

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test().Wait();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static async Task Test()
        {
            var foo = new Foo();
            var bar2 = new Bar2();

            object resultObject = await CallGetByReflection(foo, bar2);

            IBar result = (IBar)resultObject;
            result.WriteOut();

            //or

            if (resultObject is Bar)
            {
                ((Bar)resultObject).Something();
            }
            else if (resultObject is Bar2)
            {
                ((Bar2)resultObject).SomethingElse();
            }
        }

        private static async Task<object> CallGetByReflection(IFoo foo, IBar bar)
        {
            var method = typeof(IFoo).GetMethod(nameof(IFoo.Get));
            var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(bar.GetType());
            var task = (Task) generic.Invoke(foo, new[] {bar});

            await task.ConfigureAwait(false);

            var resultProperty = task.GetType().GetProperty("Result");
            return resultProperty.GetValue(task);
        }

        public interface IBar
        {
            void WriteOut();
        }
        public class Bar : IBar
        {
            public void Something()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Something");
            }
            public void WriteOut()
            {
                Console.WriteLine(nameof(Bar));
            }
        }
        public class Bar2 : IBar
        {
            public void SomethingElse()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SomethingElse");
            }
            public void WriteOut()
            {
                Console.WriteLine(nameof(Bar2));
            }
        }
        public interface IFoo
        {
            Task<T> Get<T>(T o) where T : IBar;
        }
        public class Foo : IFoo
        {
            public async Task<T> Get<T>(T o) where T : IBar
            {
                await Task.Delay(100);
                return o;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**: Here is a extension method to simplify the process

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static async Task<object> InvokeAsync(this MethodInfo @this, object obj, params object[] parameters)
    {
        var task = (Task)@this.Invoke(obj, parameters);
        await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
        var resultProperty = task.GetType().GetProperty("Result");
        return resultProperty.GetValue(task);
    }
}
```

This turns `CallGetByReflection` in to

```
private static Task<object> CallGetByReflection(IFoo foo, IBar bar)
{
    var method = typeof(IFoo).GetMethod(nameof(IFoo.Get));
    var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(bar.GetType());
    return generic.InvokeAsync(foo, new[] {bar});
}
```

---

**UPDATE 2**: Here is a new extension method that works with any awaitable type instead of only tasks by using `dynamic` and `GetAwaiter()`

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static async Task<object> InvokeAsync(this MethodInfo @this, object obj, params object[] parameters)
    {
        dynamic awaitable = @this.Invoke(obj, parameters);
        await awaitable;
        return awaitable.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: Compiler error CS0656: Der vom Compiler angeforderte Member "Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo.Create" fehlt. This points to the awaitable after "return" in the last example.

Comment: @ygoe Add the package Microsoft.CSharp to your project

Comment: Please note that `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` blocks the execution control itself.

Comment: @Rzassar No it will not, because we did `await awaitable;` the line before `return awaitable.GetAwaiter().GetResult();` we are guaranteed that  the task is in a completed state, therefor `GetResult()` will be a non-blocking call because the result will be available.

Comment: a direct casts also works

`var method = typeof(IFoo).GetMethod(nameof(IFoo.Get));
var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(bar.GetType();
var result = await (dynamic)generic.Invoke(foo, parameters);`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain how would you recommend modifying your extension method to handle a method with no return object (i.e. public async Task Whatever())?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain What do you think about changing the return type of your extension method to Task<object?> and returning @ this.ReturnType == typeof(Task) ? null : awaitable.GetAwaiter().GetResult();

Answer (score 19):

Based on your example you know type of returned object at compile time -> `IFoo`, so you can use normal casting `(IFoo)`

```
var method = typeof(IFoo).GetMethod(nameof(IFoo.Get));
var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(IBar));
var task = (Task<IBar>)generic.Invoke(foo, new [] { bar2 });

IBar result = await task;
```

If you don't know a type at compile time, then use `dynamic` keyword

```
var method = typeof(IFoo).GetMethod(nameof(IFoo.Get));
var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(bar2.GetType());
dynamic task = generic.Invoke(foo, new [] { bar2 });

IBar result = await task;
```

But if type of the task not a `Task<iFoo>` at runtime - exception will be thrown
And if you need concrete type of `IBar` then

```
var concreteResult = Convert.ChangeType(result, bar2.GetType());
```

Comment: `var task = (Task<IBar>)generic.Invoke(foo, new[] { bar2 });` throws `InvalidCastException` Unable to cast object of type `'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Bar2>'` to type `'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<IBar>'`

Comment: `dynamic task = generic.Invoke(foo, new [] { bar2 }); IBar result = await task;` always returns `null`

Comment: @user2321864 instead of doing `method.MakeGenericMethod(bar2.GetType());` you need to do `method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(IBar));` then the first example will work. `Task<T>` is not covariant so you can't cast `Task<Bar2>` to `Task<IBar>`

Comment: @user2321864, `dynamic task ...` have nothing to do with what is returned by `Get` method. I think you need check behavior of the `Get` method.

Answer (score 7):

On top of @ScottChamberlain [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39679855/3030793) (which is great ) I'll suggest a small improvement on `InvokeAsync` method to return `Task<T>` rather than `Task<object>`. Besides that it would be useful having a second method returning `Task`, which isn't supported by `InvokeAsync`.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace System.Reflection
{
    public static class MethodInfoExtensions
    {
        public static async Task<T> InvokeAsync<T>(this MethodInfo methodInfo, object obj, params object[] parameters)
        {
            dynamic awaitable = methodInfo.Invoke(obj, parameters);
            await awaitable;
            return (T)awaitable.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        public static async Task InvokeAsync(this MethodInfo methodInfo, object obj, params object[] parameters)
        {
            dynamic awaitable = methodInfo.Invoke(obj, parameters);
            await awaitable;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy and simple sample code

```
object[] param = {null};
var method = await (Task<bool>)typeof(YourClassName).GetMethod("YourMethodName",System.Reflection.BidingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).Invoke(InstanceOfYourClass, param);
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use "result" property to avoid "await" keyword and should not decalre "async" in method.

```
var method = typeof(IFoo).GetMethod(nameof(IFoo.Get));
var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(IBar));
var task = (Task<IBar>)generic.Invoke(foo, new [] { bar2 });

var resultProperty = task.GetProperty("Result");
var result = resultProperty.GetValue(task);
var convertedResult = Convert.ChangeType(result, bar2.GetType());
```